# Ant unable to load properties files with jenkins for Android source code?

Tags: android, ant, jenkins

I am a newbie for jenkins and ant. i am currently trying to build source code which is stored local on my machine running on ubuntu. I have provided path of android and java precisely. When i am trying to build this project i am getting this below error.

```
Console Output

    Started by user Pawankumar Dubey
    Building in workspace /home/administrator/administrator/repo_sync
    [ant] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/ApacheANT/bin/ant -file build.xml clean debug
    Buildfile: /home/administrator/administrator/repo_sync/sdk/files/ant/build.xml
      [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource anttasks.properties. It could not be found.
      [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. It could not be found.

    -check-env:

    BUILD FAILED
    /home/administrator/administrator/repo_sync/sdk/files/ant/build.xml:392: Problem: failed to create task or type checkenv
    Cause: The name is undefined.
    Action: Check the spelling.
    Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
    Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.


    Total time: 0 seconds
    Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Here is the path of my build.xml

```
!-- ********************* Custom Tasks ******************** -->
    <!-- ******************************************************* -->

    <!-- jar file from where the tasks are loaded -->
    <path id="android.antlibs">
        <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/ant-tasks.jar" />
    </path>

    <!-- Custom tasks -->
    <taskdef resource="anttasks.properties" classpathref="android.antlibs" />

    <!-- Emma configuration -->
    <property name="emma.dir" value="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib" />
    <path id="emma.lib">
        <pathelement location="${emma.dir}/emma.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${emma.dir}/emma_ant.jar" />
    </path>
    <taskdef resource="emma_ant.properties" classpathref="emma.lib" />
    <!-- End of emma configuration -->
```

I am not getting how anttasks.properties and emma_ant.properties are not found. Is there any inclusion needs to be done in Ant path or any things else to resolve it.

**Please Note : i have configured Android path for SDK which i have downloaded but jenkins also has folder as andoid-sdk as /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk  which seems incomplete as not all folder is and files are seen like adb and others.**

Comment: Per error, from the target '-check-env' it is not able to look & run defined taskdef/macrodef : checkenv . Do you have them includeded from complaining line # 392 ?.

Comment: From line 390 to 393 i have <!-- Basic Ant + SDK check -->
    <target name="-check-env">
        <checkenv />
    </target>